# Unpacking a list returned from function to multiple variables via mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I'm using the sentiment analyzer vader from `library(vader)`

For a given string it returns a named character vector with various attributes.  For example,

```
> get_vader("How are you doing?")
                                         compound       pos       neu       neg but_count 
        0         0         0         0         0         0         1         0         0
```

I want to create a vader score for a given column in my data.frame, but I want to "unpack" the pos, neu, and neg, values with a single call, rather than having to call the function three times for the same variable.

Example:

```
test = data.frame(a = "how are you doing today?")
test %>% mutate(vader_pos = get_vader(a)['pos'], 
vader_neg = get_vader(a)['neg'], 
vader_neu = get_vader(a)['neu'])
```

How do I avoid calling the `get_vader` function three times, and simply unpack all three variables simultaneously to the appropriate columns?

Comment: I don't have `vader`.  Would you `dput(get_vader(a))` please so that I have something to work with?

Comment: `>dput(get_vader(test$a))
c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, compound = 0, pos = 0, neu = 1, neg = 0, but_count = 0
)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(vader)
#Data
test = data.frame(a = "how are you doing today?",b='Hello you')
#Create dataframe with results
df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,sapply(test,get_vader)))
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 compound pos neu neg but_count
a  0  0  0  0  0        0   0   1   0         0
b  0  0  0  0  1        0   0   0   0         0
```